# PHP: Send an email with the data the user filled in a form, only after the user hit "send"? (the data is an array)

Tags: php, arrays, forms, email

I´m very newbie on PHP, and programming in general, and I´m still reading my manual. I´m trying some excercises, and creating some simple tests of my own.

I have a form, with some checkboxes and select items. The user complete the form and it shows some output. It´s like a little game, where the user selects some answers, and the scripts shows a number that´s his/her score.

Now, I would like to receive an email each time a user completes the game, with all the answers.

The users completes some checkboxes and select items, so, all answers are arrays (So, I´ve tried $message_answer2 = $_POST['answer2']; and it won´t work).

So, I´ve tried:

```
$to   = 'myown@mail.com';
$subject = 'New Game '.date("m/d/Y h:m:s");
$message_answer2 = join(', ', $_POST['answer2']);
mail($to, $subject, $message_answer2);
```

There are 2 issues with this:

- There´s a PHP error that appears: Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in ...
- An email is dispatched (a blank email) each time I just reload the page. The emails should be sent only after the user hits the "send" button of the form.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this :)

Thanks!!

Rosamunda

Comment: For the first question use implode instead.

Comment: @Aurelio: Why? join() is an alias of implode() and internally uses exactly the same code as implode().

Comment: Using implode the error is still there: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Comment: @MarcB Sorry. I forgot it was just an alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
if (isset($POST['answer2'])) {
    $to   = 'myown@mail.com';
    $subject = 'New Game '.date("m/d/Y h:m:s");
    $message_answer2 = join(', ', $_POST['answer2']);
    mail($to, $subject, $message_answer2);
}
```

I'm assuming when the user submits the form you're having it post to the current page. If that's the case then when you're originally loading the page there is no data set in $_POST['answer2'] which is why you're getting an error, and then its sending the blank message because there is no data to send. Adding that an email will be sent only if statement will make it so that only if there is data being posted to the page in 'answer2'.

Comment: Thanks! If I have more values answer3, 4, 5, etc, should I use elseif? There are some of the responses that have an "already checked" default option, so, they are already checked even if the user didn´t do anything.

Comment: If you're going to have multiple values, I'd suggest sending the data as a JSON object. Then parsing it from the POST data.

Comment: I´ve tried that single field and the email is sent, but the two errors persist (there are 2 mails sent, one because I reloaded the page, and other because I hit "send", and the " Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed" error still appears.

Comment: Read the other answers. Marc B has the right information you need when talking about the join().

Comment: Thanks! The thing is that I already have this format: <input name="answer2[]">

Comment: better to do `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { ...}` instead. This is 100% reliable, unlike checking for the presence of a field. You may rename a field and forget to update the if()

Comment: Thanks! You mean something like this? if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$message_answer2 = join(', ', $_POST['answer2']);
$message_answer3 = join(', ', $_POST['answer3']);
mail($to, $subject, $message_answer2);
}

Comment: No, it seems that $message_answer2 should be always the same, and I cannot create a different variable for each value. The thing is that it only prints the first element and not all the others if I use the same $message_answer2  for all fields...

Comment: $me = join(', ', $_POST['answer1']);
$me = join(', ', $_POST['answer2']);
$me = join(', ', $_POST['answer3']);
mail($to, $subject, $me);   It only prints inside the email the answer3 value...

Answer (score 2):

`join()` is for use on arrays. Unless you've used the PHP-specific array notation on your form's field names `<input name="answer2[]">`, PHP will **NOT** make `$_POST['answer2']` an array - it'll just be an ordinary string.

If your form looks like

```
<input name="answer2" ...>
<input name="answer2" ...>
```

then you're still only get a single string value in $_POST. You must use the `[]` notation to tell PHP it should create an array and add each individual answer2 to that array. When not in array mode, PHP will simply overwrite `$_POST['answer2']` with each answer2 value it finds in the form data.

Comment: Just a note: Yes, I already did put the square brackets:  answer2[] :)

Comment: I'd suggest doing a `var_dump($_POST['answer2'])`, then, and make sure it IS coming through as an array. You'd not be getting that error message if it was an array.

Comment: Thanks! I´ve changed the code to replace it with var_dump, and the email is sent, blank, but it prints at the webpage this: array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "answer2" }

Comment: This is what I have at the form: <select name="answer2[]">
<option value="yes">yes</option>
<option value="no">no</option>
</select>

Comment: Looks ok in that case. Do the `if()` check suggested by Tyler below to skip sending the email when the form is initially loaded. His version will send it only when the form is submitted via POST.

Comment: yay! Thanks! So far, the error have dissapeared and the form only gets off when people actually submits it. Thanks!